# Powershell Remote Commands

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to run the get-service command on a remote machine in powershell. After doing some research, it appears this is only possilbe n powershell 2 CTP, which I cannot use as I need to use the version of powershell installed with exchange, which is usualy 1. It seems the -computerName switch is only availible in  get-service in ps 2.
So i've pretty much decided its a no-go, but wanted to see if anyone here had an clever solutions before I give up on it.

Comment: Sam, most of the "remote' capabilities from PowerShell V1 are either via WMI and/or using .NET classes directly.  /n Software also has an PowerShell SSH server which works with V1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can go directly to WMI the get the service information.

```
gwmi Win32_Service -computername FOO
```

Answer (score 6):

Those are all fine answers but they only help you with Services.  What you want is somethign that will work with anything:

**WINRS is your best friend!**

```
[4120:0]PS> winrs -r:localhost powershell get-service h*

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  hidserv            Human Interface Device Access
Running  hkmsvc             Health Key and Certificate Management
Stopped  HomeGroupListener  HomeGroup Listener
Running  HomeGroupProvider  HomeGroup Provider
```

BTW - WINRS uses WS-MAN which means it will work across firewalls.

Experiment! Enjoy! Engage!

Jeffrey Snover [MSFT]
Windows Management Partner Architect

Comment: To set up your machines, start with the command "winrs quickconfig".

Answer (score 4):

This will work in v1:

[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController]::GetServices("String machineName")